# How to uninstall Chromium browser

Tags: chrome, browser, uninstall, bodhi

I am using **Bodhi Linux** how to uninstall the Chromium Browser?

Comment: Might this help? https://bodhilinux.boards.net/thread/411/uninstall-chromium-solved

Comment: Thanks @Peregrino69 it helped `sudo apt purge bodhi-chromium && sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: Do feel free to answer your own question and accept your own answer. Doing that prevents this from popping up as an Unanswered question somewhere down the line.

Comment: @Peregrino69 please answer it and yes it will be useful for others as well.

Comment: As requested. Please don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this posting](https://bodhilinux.boards.net/thread/411/uninstall-chromium-solved) in Bodhi Linux community, commands to remove Bodhi's version of Chromium are:

```
sudo apt purge bodhi-chromium && sudo apt autoremove
```